# Automapper, calculate value if a property value starts with a value

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I would like to create a mapper that use the same class in the source and destination (copy the object) but if the property value of "ColumnName" starts with '*', double the "Value" property value.
This is the class:

```
public class CustomerDatabaseParameter
{

    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }

}
```

This is the result that I need:

Example 1:

```
From:
ColumnName = "*xxxx";
Value = 50.0;

To:
ColumnName = "*xxxx";
Value = 100.0;
```

Example 2:

```
From:
ColumnName = "www";
Value = 50.0;

To:
ColumnName = "www";
Value = 50.0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any expression you like inside a `ResolveUsing`. Just make sure you return a type that matches the destination type.

```
CreateMap<CustomerDatabaseParameter, CustomerDatabaseParameter>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, o => o.ResolveUsing(
         src => src.ColumnName.StartsWith("*") ? (src.Value * 2) : src.Value
     ));
```

Comment: It works but the value is the same of the origin... Any idea?

Comment: Hm maybe there is a space in the ColumnName? Try `src => src.ColumnName.Trim().StartsWith("*")`. You can add a debugger breakpoint inside the expression to see if it matches.

Comment: I had insert the CreateMap into var map =
                    new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                        cfg.CreateMap....).CreateMapper(); and then I user map.map<CustomerDatabaseParameter>(source). Is it right?

Comment: That should work if you use an instance of the mapper. Or if you are using the static Mapper: `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<...>(); }); var dest = Mapper.Map<CustomerDatabaseParameter>(src);`